# net/ssh gem breaks messaging/form submission in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, pusher

I installed the gem net/ssh, after encountering this error

```
~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fog-1.32.0/lib/fog/joyent/compute.rb:3:in `require': cannot load such file -- net/ssh (LoadError)
```

However, it broke the messaging system that uses Pusher to push messages to the pages that subscribed to that channel. I think it is a SSH related problem, I can not solve it since I don't know enough about SSH, connections etc.

Is there any workaround to overcome this error, or do I have to install net/ssh gem?